# CSS Performance: Multiple selectors with unique value vs. unique selectors with duplicate values

Tags: css, performance

Given a set of CSS rules with some overlapping declarations, there are two main approaches for structuring the styles.

One the one hand, we can declare each property once, but use selectors  multiple times:

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
     color: #444;
}

.one   { // more specific styles }
.two   { // more specific styles }
.three { // more specific styles }
```

On the other hand, we can use each selector exactly once, but with duplicate properties:

```
.one {
     color: #444;
     // more specific styles
}

.two {
     color: #444;
     // more specific styles
}

.three {
     color: #444;
     // more specific styles
}
```

Theoretically there is a third option, which is isolating every commonly used property in its own class, i.e. `.grey-stuff { color: #444; }` but that's would oftentimes end up in messy HTML.

Of the two approaches outlined above, which one should be preferred, if any?

The background of the question is maintenance of a larger CSS code base. I'm not sure if there are relevant differences in render performance, but I could imagine there being advantages in total CSS file size and development convenience.

Comment: Performance will depend on your HTML as well, not just your selectors.

Comment: What have you done to test performance?  Have you tried to time anything?  Are you currently experiencing an issue you believe is related to CSS?  Questions about "preference" are outside the scope of SO as it generates opinion based responses instead of fact based ones

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Selector Chain Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624164/css-selector-chain-performance)

Comment: I've added some background for the question. The things I've found regarding the issue almost exclusively discuss performance of individual selectors. I've also considered applying each approach to a larger code base and looking at the CSS output in terms of structure and size.

Comment: Indeed, that question has a direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it depends.  CSS classes should describe functionality rather than presentation, so a class of `grey-stuff` would not be recommended while `menu-stuff` would be more sensible.  Thus the answer comes down to what `one`, `two`, and `three` actually are.  If they represent similar classes of content it may make sense to combine their styles together (as in example A).  If it's plausible that you will end up changing individual properties later then it would make sense to keep them separate even though they are duplicated.

In most cases it's probably a better idea to go with the first option, though.  Most likely these classes are dealing with similar constructs.

As for performance, it would be so irrelevant here that I wouldn't worry about it.  Instead do what is better for maintainability and spend time optimizing something else.